# std::unordered_map with custom allocator / local allocator does not compile

Tags: c++, allocation

I have a pretty simple custom/local allocator. My goal is to use an array on the stack as the allocating portion of memory. It appears to work in `std::vector` but when I try to plug it in to `std::unordered_map` it fails to compile. gcc 7.4.0's error messages are pretty impenetrable. Something along the lines of:

```
hashtable_policy.h:2083:26: error: no matching function for call to
‘MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<std::pair<const int, std::string>, 500>::
MonotonicIncreasingAllocator(std::__detail::_Hashtable_alloc<MonotonicIncreasingAllocator
<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int, std::string>, false>, 500> >::
__node_alloc_type&)’
   
    __value_alloc_type __a(_M_node_allocator());
```

Clang 7.1.0 is a bit more manageable. Scrolling from an error like `error: no matching conversion for functional-style cast from 'const std::_Hashtable . . .` I find:

```
hashmap_custom_alloc.cpp:11:5: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from
    'MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<const int,
    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >, false>, [...]>' to 'const
    MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<std::__detail::_Hash_node_base *, [...]>' for 1st argument
  MonotonicIncreasingAllocator(const MonotonicIncreasingAllocator& rhs) = default;
  ^
```

Makes it a bit clearer this `std::__detail::_Hash_node_base` bit is getting in the way. Here is the code, neither unordered_map declaration compiles:

```
#include <array>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

template<class T, std::size_t max_size>
class MonotonicIncreasingAllocator
{
public:
    MonotonicIncreasingAllocator() : _index{0} {}

    using type = MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<T, max_size>;
    using other = MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<T, max_size>;

    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;
    using is_always_equal = std::true_type;
        
    template<class U> 
    using rebind = MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<U, max_size>;

    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        T* r = _data.begin() + _index;
        _index += n;
        return r;
    }

    constexpr void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("MontonicIncreasingAllocator can never deallocate()!");
    }

private:
    std::size_t _index;
    std::array<T, max_size> _data;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    using key = int;
    using value = string;
    using item = pair<key, value>;

    using alloc = MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<item, 500>;
    alloc a0;
    alloc a1;
    vector<item, alloc> v0(a0);
    vector<int, alloc> v1;
    // unordered_map<key, value, hash<key>, equal_to<key>, alloc> m; // doesn't compile
    // unordered_map<key, value, hash<key>, equal_to<key>, alloc> m(500, a1); // doesn't compile

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI: Allocators are meant to return memory for _unconstructed objects_ which will then later be constructed using [`std::allocator_traits::construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits/construct) (effectively placement `new`). If you are using a `std::array<T,...>`, then this means you are returning constructed objects -- and for non-trivially-destructible type `T`s such as `std::string`, you would be overwriting a valid object without calling its destructor, which is UB. Most allocators work directly with byte sequences, not `T` sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An allocator of type `T` must be rebindable to an allocator of type `U` -- this is why there is the `rebind` template.

To do this you must offer a way to conversion-construct from a type `U` to a type `T` e.g. a constructor that constructs from `MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<U, ...>&`, such as:

```cpp
template <typename U>
MonotonicIncreasingAllocator( const MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<U, max_size>& )
```

You might notice a problem that immediately comes from this: an `array<U,max_size>` cannot necessarily be copied to an `array<T,max_size>`; and due to this, you will want to rethink your allocator design.<sup>[1]</sup>

For legacy reasons, the C++ "Allocator" model is meant to be copyable. This requirement makes it difficult to work with allocators that itself contain state, rather than indirectly point to state.

**Note:** The reason this may have worked for `vector` is because an allocator of type `T` doesn't get rebound on a `vector<T>`, since it only needs to allocate `n` instances of `T`. This is not true for more complex data structures like a `map`, `set`, `unordered_map`, etc -- since there may be nodes of objects or other contiguous sequences internally used.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> Stateful allocators are stored directly into the containers that use them. This means that a `vector<T,MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<T,N>>` will now also store the allocator itself, containing an `array<T,N>`, directly inside of the `vector` class, in addition to its own data -- which is wasteful. Copying or even moving a container with this allocator would be an extremely expensive operation.

Additionally, by storing the data directly inside of the allocator, conversion-construction requires a copy of the entire internal `std::array` object, which means that the rebinding constructs a *new* object that refers to a different monotonic structure than the allocator that was being rebound -- which isn't ideal.

You should look into the architecture that's used in [`std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator) for better inspiration. The `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator` holds onto 1 data type: a `std::memory_resource` pointer, which makes rebinding cheap, and storage of this allocator cheap. The `memory_resource` is type-ambiguous and passed by indirection, which allows for allocators after being rebound to use and refer to the same memory pool.

Comment: _"Non-stateless"_ :D

Comment: Changed to _"Stateful"_ so it doesn't sound as weird :P

Comment: I'm totally confounded. How am I supposed to convert an arbitrary type `U` into an arbitrary type `T`? This rebind business makes no sense to me.

Comment: The C++ allocator model always deals out `T` pointers, which is why rebinding exists. It doesn't mean that the *allocator logic* is only implemented in terms of `T` everywhere. This would be bad for code-bloat on expensive allocator logic. This is why most allocators extract their common allocation logic into some other class that is indirectly pointed to by the allocator. This is what `polymorphic_allocator` does with `memory_resource`. The resource isn't tied to any type, but `polymorphic_allocator` just copies around the resource pointer

Comment: It's a lot easier to write allocator _logic_ as something non-type specific managing `void*` data. If you do this, then you can write an allocator _wrapper_ `template` that deals specifically in `T` types that _internally_ uses a pointer to your underlying allocator logic. Rebinding in this case is just a pointer-copy. The C++ Allocator model is easier to think of as being a _"handle to a memory resource"_, rather than as itself an allocator

Answer (score 0):

As @Human-Compiler talked about in his answer, one should not couple the allocated data with the allocator. The solution is rather simple: **pass in a pointer from the desired array-on-the-stack**. You needn't bother with all the allocator-wrapper nonsense one finds in this thread and elsewhere. In SOLID terms, the data is injected as a dependency into the allocator.

I still find the rebind interface awfully curious. It's clearly poor design that we're stuck with. Beyond writing the `struct rebind { other...` archaic alias, **one must also provide a copy constructor from a rebound type**. The latter *is hardly documented*, if at all.

```
#include <array>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

struct SharedArray 
{
    uint8_t* data;
    uint64_t index;
};
template<class T>
class MonotonicIncreasingAllocator
{
public:
    MonotonicIncreasingAllocator(SharedArray& a) : _data{a} {}

    template<class U>
    MonotonicIncreasingAllocator(const MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<U>& rhs)
     : _data{const_cast<MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<U>&>(rhs).data()} {}

    using type = MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<T>;
    using other = MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<T>;

    using value_type = T;
    using size_type = std::size_t;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using propagate_on_container_move_assignment = std::true_type;
    using is_always_equal = std::true_type;
    
    template<class U> 
    using rebind = MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<U>;

    T* allocate(std::size_t n)
    {
        T* r = _data.data + _data.index;
        _data.index += n * sizeof(T);
        return r;
    }

    constexpr void deallocate(T* p, std::size_t n)
    {
        return;
    }

    SharedArray& data()
    {
        return _data;
    }


private:
    SharedArray& _data;
};

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    using key = int;
    using value = string;
    using item = pair<key, value>;
    std::array<uint8_t, 4096> arr; // allocate enough, here but a page
    SharedArray sharr;
    sharr.index = 0;
    sharr.data = arr.begin();

    using alloc = MonotonicIncreasingAllocator<item>;
    alloc a0(sharr);
    alloc a1(sharr);
    vector<item, alloc> v0(a0);
    unordered_map<key, value, hash<key>, equal_to<key>, alloc> m(500, a1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Following error on GCC;

```
Required from here
/usr/include/c++/11.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:191:21: error: static assertion failed: unordered container must have the same value_type as its allocator
```

Comment: Also another error: error: cannot convert ‘uint8_t*’ {aka ‘unsigned char*’} to ‘std::__detail::_Hash_node_base**’ in initialization
  129 |         T* r = _data.data + _data.index